# Why do we remove the origin from the topological space when deriving anyons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, bosons, anyons

When we derive the existence of anyons in 'r-space' where r = r1 - r2 and r1 and r2 are the parameters describing two particles called '1' and '2', we remove the point r=0 so that 'the two particles do not ever occupy the same position'. However we know that bosons can occupy the same position, so why do we force this constraint?

Is it just to search for the existence of non-bosonic particles?